# Install windows 10 on my iMac

Tags: bootcamp, windows, macos

I'm trying to follow the instructions found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSbXMoy0PPM) to install windows 10 on my iMac. But I get this error `The installer disc could not be found` as shown below:

[image]

This is my iMac specs:

[image]

Any advice guys please?

Comment: Well, do you have a disk inserted?

Comment: I tried couple of things. 1- I tried putting the windows 10 .iso file on a flash disk which is connected to the mac and gave the same error. 2- I got an empty DVD, copied the .iso file to it and burnt it and inserted then inserted it and the same message appears.

Comment: Any advice guys please????

Comment: Windows 10 isn't supported on that machine - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204990 Even if you get it to work, it won't have the necessary drivers.